# xhrPost works differently with Firefox and IE

Tags: ajax, dojo, struts, request

I have a problem with Struts 1.3 and Dojo.
I use xhrPost for an ajax call, like this:

```
dojo.xhrPost( {
    url: contesto+"/my_struts_action.do",
    content: {valore: valore, phase: indexPhase, field: indexResult, property: tipoCampo}, 
    handleAs: "text",
    sync: true,
    timeout: 50000,

    // The LOAD function will be called on a successful response.
    load: function(response, ioArgs) { // 
    return response; // 
  },

  // The ERROR function will be called in an error case.
  error: function(response, ioArgs) { // 
    console.error("HTTP status code: ", ioArgs.xhr.status); // 
    return response; // 
    }
  });
```

this is Action method:

```
public ActionForward saveResultValue(ActionMapping actionMapping,
        ActionForm actionForm, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ModuleCompileException {

    String value = request.getParameter("valore");
              ...
}
```

I use a request.getParameter("valore") and I have different result in FF or IE (Firefox or Internet Explorer).
In FF, I receive a correct string with special characters, but in IE, I receive a wrong string.

For example:
I send "unità" from xhrPost method.
with FF, struts method receives a correct string, with IE receives "unitÃ".

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is because of browser differences in xhrPost. More likely it would be the encoding headers from the server or the encoding declaration at the beginning of your html header. Browsers should always answer requests in the encoding that the page was received in.

Check the server header (assuming utf -8):

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

and the html head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

See here:
http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/6037

Make sure that both browsers think the page is in the same encoding by using view->encoding on the top menu and seeing what is currently selected. And, like recommended in the referenced ticket use firebug or a similar tool to inspect the headers from your server.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem.
I added headers property at xhrPost call.

```
dojo.xhrPost( {
    url: contesto+"/distribution/update_result_value.do",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" },
    content: {valore: valore, phase: indexPhase, field: indexResult, property: tipoCampo}, 
    handleAs: "text",
    sync: true,
    timeout: 50000,

    // The LOAD function will be called on a successful response.
    load: function(response, ioArgs) { // 
    return response; // 
  },

  // The ERROR function will be called in an error case.
  error: function(response, ioArgs) { // 
    console.error("HTTP status code: ", ioArgs.xhr.status); // 
    return response; // 
    }
  });
```

Probably, IE use a page charset (in my case, iso) in the xhrPost call. Headers property specific which charset should use the call.

Thanks!